# Questions about Substring() in C#

Tags: c#

I am not a C# programmer & need help. I have some questions:

when I have the string `text='My car is nice'`, then what would be the output of the following lines:

```
(1) text.Substring(1,1);
(2) text.Substring(6,1);
(3) text.Substring(1,4).Replace('c','a');
(4) text.Substring(1,10).Replace('a','b').Replace(' ','t');
```

My conclusions are:

```
(1) 'y'
(2) ' is nice M'     <== here, I started from 6 until 1 (or do I need to swap 1&6?)
(3) 'y c'
(4) 'ytcbrtist'      <== here I replaced a with b & the space lines with t
```

I hope someone can help.

Best regards,

Comment: How about you try it out my friend.

Comment: 1) Why don't you test it yourself? 2) [Documentation clearly states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) that second argument to String.Substring() is a *length* parameter

Comment: Via the MSDN Reference for the [String.Substring(int startIndex, int length)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) function: _Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the doc of [String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it says that:

> public string Substring(
>       int startIndex,
>       int length
>   )

Then:

```
(1) text.Substring(1,1);
(2) text.Substring(6,1);
(3) text.Substring(1,4).Replace('c','a');
(4) text.Substring(1,10).Replace('a','b').Replace(' ','t');

(1) 'y' // Indice 1 length 1
(2) ' ' // Indice 6 length 1  
(3) 'y aa' // Indice 1 length 4 and replacements 
(4) 'ytcbrtistn'// Indice 1 length 10 and replacements
```

See it [live](http://ideone.com/ibDLT7)

Answer (score 1):

```
1)'y'    OK
2)' ' The sixth character is 'r'. And the next one is space ' '.
3)'y aa' . You are taking 4 chars starting from first. It's 'y ca' . Later You replace c with a. 
4)'ytcbrtistn' . You take 10 chars starting from 2nd one. 'y car is n' . You replace a with b -> 'y cbr is n' . Later replace space with t.
```